# Display result table based on selected search criteria and search keyword

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

Assume that I have table consist of a list of students. To search for a student, I have a drop down list on the criteria I can select from to search by, such as search by ID, search by hometown, search by gender, search by max GPA, etc. After I select the criteria I'd like to search by, I proceed to enter the keyword.

Currently, I have 2 variables, `category` which is the variable to store the option/criteria I chose to search by, and `keyword` which is the word I enter in the input box.

What should I do if I want to compare the keyword I entered to all objects in the column of the criteria I selected? Let's say I select search by hometown, when I enter "New", the result table will show all results with hometown with the word "New" in it. I already used `toUpperCase()` because I don't want to use case-sensitive search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below code snippet of working filter functionality, here I am using search field along with drop-down to select a category, and I guess this would be helpful:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  this.json = {
    "Students": [{
        "id": "1",
        "hometown": "London",
        "gender": "Male",
        "GPA": "8",
        "name": "Lee",
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "hometown": "NY",
        "gender": "Male",
        "GPA": "9",
        "name": "Shaldon",
      }, {
        "id": "3",
        "hometown": "Paris",
        "gender": "Female",
        "GPA": "7",
        "name": "Julie",
      }
    ]
  };
  
  this.renderTable = function(Students) {
    var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
    tbody.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < Students.length; i++) {
      var tr = "<tr>";
      tr += "<td>ID</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].id + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>HomeTown</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].hometown + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>Gender</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].gender + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>GPA</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].GPA + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>NAME</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].name + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<hr>";
      tbody.innerHTML += tr;
    }
  }

  this.renderTable(this.json.Students);

  console.log(this.json.Students);
  //code for filtering//
  this.Filter = function() {
    var search = document.getElementById('search');
    var category = document.getElementById('category');
    var filteredObj = this.json.Students;
    filteredObj = $.map(this.json.Students, function(val, key) {
      if (search.value === val[category.value]) return val;
    });
    filteredObj.length>0 ? this.renderTable(filteredObj) : this.renderTable(this.json.Students);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>

<input id="search" type="search">
<select id = "category">
<option value = "select">select</option>
   <option value = "id">ID</option>
   <option value = "hometown">HomeTown</option>
   <option value = "gender">Gender</option>
   <option value = "GPA">GPA</option>
   <option value = "name">NAME</option>
  </select>
<button onclick="Filter()">Filter</button>

<table>
  <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow that is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you so much!